# Why are my Jacoco Reports not reflecting Unit Test coverage on my Android Project?

Tags: android, jacoco, android-studio-3.0

I have used the default basic template from Android Studio. I added a failing test to make sure everything was working...

```
class ExampleUnitTest {
    @Test
    fun addition_isCorrect() {
        assertEquals(4, 2 + 2)
    }
    @Test
    fun addition_isCorrect2() {
        assertEquals(3, 2 + 2)
    }
}
```

I ran `build.gradle` and saw it fail. Next I added the following to the app `build.gradle`

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        ...
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled true
        }
    }
}
```

I ran `gradle test` and it fails as expected but when I run `gradle createDebugCoverageReport` it doesn't fail. The report does get created but doesn't reflect the coverage of the tests I have added (which makes sense since the tests appear not to be getting ran).

What am I missing and how do I get the Jacoco report to properly reflect the coverage. This should be able to be recreated using Android Studio and a basic activity project.

Here is an example of a test I tried to add to add coverage...

```
@Test
fun addition_isCorrect() {
    val test = FirstFragment();
    test.onDestroyView()
    Assert.assertEquals(4, 2+2)
}
```

I know it isn't a very good test but it is more to show that the coverage is working for now.

### Update

I did notice that I only have a `/build/reports/coverage/androidTest` folder and not a `/build/reports/coverage/test` folder to reflect the unit test coverage. So it appears only the integration tests are getting ran.

I also tried this...

https://about.codecov.io/blog/code-coverage-for-android-development-using-kotlin-jacoco-github-actions-and-codecov/

and

https://gist.github.com/mrsasha/384a19f97cdeba5b5c2ea55f930fccd4

But I get

> Cannot set the value of read-only property 'classDirectories' for task ':app:testDebugUnitTestCoverage' of type org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoReport.

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution?